# How to find the length of a filtered array?

Tags: angular

Here is my database collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a52c536851fc3289875d14"),
    "device_id" : "ASDFGHJ1234567",
    "users" : [ 
        {
            "user_name" : "Athira",
            "player_level" : "beginner",
            "created_on" : "2017-01-25 09:54:40",
            "updated_on" : "2017-01-25 09:54:40",
            "status" : "Y"
        }, 
        {
            "user_name" : "Sandeep",
            "player_level" : "beginner",
            "created_on" : "2017-01-25 09:54:40",
            "updated_on" : "2017-01-25 09:54:40",
            "status" : "D"
        }
    ],
    "device_created_on" : "2017-01-25 09:54:40",
    "device_status" : "Y"
}
```

i need to list the devices and the users like the below

```
Device             No: users    Status
 ASDFGHJ1234567       2            Y
```

Here I have used ngFor for displaying this

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3">
   <tr>
   <td>Device Id</td>
   <td>Number of Users</td>
   <td>Status</td>
   <td>Action</td>
   </tr>
   <tr *ngFor="let hero of users">
     <td>{{ hero.device_id}}</td>
     <td>{{ hero.users?.length }}</td>
     <td>{{ hero.device_status }}</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
```

But I need to count only those users which are have status= 'Y'. Here only  user_name = "Athira" should count

How can I implement this

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter the array like this:

```
getCount(hero: any): number {
 if (!hero || !hero.users) return 0;

 return hero.users.filter(u => u.status === 'Y').length;
}
```

Comment: compiler.es5.js:1690 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 25 in [{{ hero?.users?.filter(u => u.status === 'Y').length}}] in ng:///AppModule/testComponent.html@22:39 ("                                <td>{{ hero.device_id}}</td>
                                   <td>[ERROR ->]{{ hero?.users?.filter(u => u.status === 'Y').length}}</td>
                                   <td>

Comment: Have you tried it in a function in your typescript? I'm not sure if angular can handle this in html

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this. In your ts file let arrData be your response

```
   var data = this.arrData.users;

   var count = 0; var i=0;

   data.forEach(element => {
       if(data[i].status == "Y"){
        count++;
       }
       i++;
   });

   console.log(count); //you will get count value which is users with status 'Y'
```